# Deserialize a JSON payload to object base on JSON integer property

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have below classes:

```
public class Result<T> {
    public int code;
    public Object meta;
    public T data;
}

public class User {
    public int id;
    public String name;
}

public class Error {
    public String field;
    public String message;
}
```

I want to deserialize a `JSON` payload based on `code` field. If `code >= 10`, return `Result<ArrayList<Error>>`, otherwise return `Result<User>`

Currently, I map `JSON` to `Result<Object>` first, then check the `code` field. Based on that value I make second map to desired object.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Result<Object> tempResult = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Result<Object>>() {});

if (tempResult.code < 10) {    
    Result<User> result = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Result<User>>() {});
    return result;
} else {
    Result<ArrayList<Error>> result = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Result<ArrayList<Error>>>() {});
    return result;
}
```

Is there an elegant way to do this without deserializing it 2 times?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement custom `TypeIdResolver`:

```
class UserTypeIdResolverBase extends TypeIdResolverBase {

    @Override
    public String idFromValue(Object value) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not implemented!");
    }

    @Override
    public String idFromValueAndType(Object value, Class<?> suggestedType) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not implemented!");
    }

    @Override
    public JsonTypeInfo.Id getMechanism() {
        return JsonTypeInfo.Id.CUSTOM;
    }

    @Override
    public JavaType typeFromId(DatabindContext context, String id) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(id) < 10) {
            return context.getTypeFactory().constructType(new TypeReference<Result<User>>() {});
        }
        return context.getTypeFactory().constructType(new TypeReference<Result<List<Error>>>() {});
    }
}
```

and declare it for a `Result` class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(property = "code", use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CUSTOM, visible = true)
@JsonTypeIdResolver(UserTypeIdResolverBase.class)
class Result<T>
```